# manage github repository - mantain old script versions

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging

I want to mantain inside a repository the old versions of a script. I've created some folders named with the version number of the script. Is this the correct way of manage a github repository?
Example of the folder structure.

NB: the 1.1 and the 1.2 folders are pulled from relative branches.

```
master branch
|- 1.1
|- 1.2
|- script.php
```

Comment: Are you trying to manually emulate version control over version-controlled repository? Why not just store old versions of the script in the git commit history?

Comment: "Is this the correct way of manage a github repository?" Almost certainly not. Have you taken any Git tutorials? Have you learned about tagging?

Comment: @phd I've divided the different code versions in directorys because git will update the main script file inside the repo and this is not really what I want

Comment: @Chris I know about tags, but as my knowledge they are limited to the branches?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, @user10479680, but I don't think so. They're actually very similar to branches: both tags and branches are pointers to a commit, and they make the commit they're pointing to reachable, preventing it from being garbage collected. Branches are meant to be mutable (they can move around as branches change), but (annotated) tags are meant to be immutable (once you tag a commit that tag should always refer to that exact commit). They're great for identifying versions of things.

Comment: Ok, so when I upload an update to the repository, I just need to add a tag ?

Comment: No, not when you "upload an update". When you have a version that deserves a name, e.g. when you release a new version.